All geodesics on the usual Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^2$ are lines
I'm trying to show that, given $(\mathbb{R}^2,g)$, where $g$ is the usual Euclidean metric, that all geodesics are straight lines.
The condition I want to check is that, given a curve $c:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, we have $\nabla_{c'}c' \equiv 0  \iff$ $c$ is a straight line (i.e., of the form $c(t) = (a+t,b+mt), t\geq 0$ or $c(t) = (a,b+t)$, with initial points $(a,b)$).
Now, for the Euclidean connection, given vector fields $X,Y$ along the curve $c$, we have that $\nabla_{X} Y (c(t)) = DY_e(c(t)) X(c(t))$, where $Y_e$ is any extension of $Y$ to an open neighborhood of the curve $c$ (needed so that we can make sense of the derivative), agreeing with $Y$ on the curve $c$.
Now, it is easy to check that all straight lines are geodesics.
However, I'm having trouble checking the converse. Namely, I want to check that, given curve $c:t \mapsto (c_1(t),c_2(t))$, that $\nabla_{c'}c' = Dc'_e (c(t)) c'(t) = 0$, but I'm not sure how to express these extensions $c'_e$ of $c'$ in a nice way. I found this answer but its not very constructive, so that I can't compute the differential using it.

We're just doing plain calculus here. $\nabla_{c'}c' = \nabla_{\partial/\partial t}c'=c''=0$, so $c'$ is constant.

I don't see why its the usual double derivative. By definition, we have$\nabla_{c'}c' = Dc' (c(t)) c'(t)$, which is matrix $\times$ vector. Why is this $c''$?

In particular, the above simplifies to terms involving $c_1'$ and $c_2'$, whereas your answer only has second derivatives of these components.

It is far less clumsy to work with the actual definition of the covariant derivative as a directional derivative: Take any curve $\gamma(t)$ with $\gamma(0)=c(0)$ and $\gamma'(0)=c'(0)$ and (covariantly) differentiate $X(\gamma(t))$ at $t=0$. That is, $$\nabla_{c'(0)}X = \dfrac D{dt}\Big|_{t=0} X(\gamma(t)) = \dfrac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} c'(t) = c''(0).$$
Here, to be more pedantic, you can choose local coordinates $(t,u)$ with $c$ given by $u=0$ (and if you want to extend, take your extension independent of $u$). This assumes, of course, that the curve (locally) is embedded, and it uses the standard lemma from basic differentiable manifolds that given a non-vanishing vector field $Z$, we can choose local coordinates $(t,u)$ with $Z=\partial/\partial t$. Then your local smooth extension is given by $X_e(t,u) = X(t)=c'(t)$ and you can differentiate $X(t)$ as you wish, noting that $DX_e(c(0))(c'(0)) = \begin{bmatrix} c''(0) & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix} = c''(0)$.

Thank you so much, your second paragraph makes sense! For your briefer argument in the beginning (I'm assuming $X = c'$), how do you directly get $\frac{D}{dt}|{t=0}X(\gamma(t)) = \frac{d}{dt}|{t=0}c'(t)$? How does this fall out from using "the actual definition of the covariant derivative as a directional derivative"?

My question might also be because I'm unsure about what you mean with notation $\frac{D}{dt}$ - I've only seen this used in do Carmo, for ex., where he writes $\frac{D}{dt}V \equiv \nabla_{c'} V$ to express covariant derivative of a vector field $V$ along a pre-specified curve $c$ (implicit in the first expression).

First, in our case, $D=d$, as we're working in a vector space. Second, in the case of a submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$, the induced connection is given by projecting the usual derivative (which is in $\Bbb R^n$) onto the tangent space, using the metric. Third, and most generally, this notation is used — yes — as you specified in DoCarmo. Personally, I prefer to work with connections given in terms of local moving frames differential forms, and then I don't have to mess with this well-definedness of local smooth extensions. :)

Thanks for the response! I haven't encountered "moving frames" yet, so I'm unfortunately restricted to more brute arguments. But by your "second" point (i.e., induced connection given by projection), do you mean that as justification for the fact that $\frac{D}{dt}|{t=0}X(\gamma(t))) = \frac{d}{dt}|{t = 0}c'(t)$? Because I'm not sure I see that still.

For this discussion, use my first comment. Our Riemannian manifold is $\Bbb R^2$, so the connection is just usual differentiation of a vector function.

Got it. But for vector fields $X,Y$, isn't the Euclidean connection $\nabla_X Y = DY(p) X(p) $? So that here, $\nabla_{c'(0)} X = \nabla_{c'(0)} c'(0)$. By your longer description, I see that this indeed equals $c''(0)$.  But when can we say that $\nabla_X Y = Y'$ just "by inspection" (for the Euclidean connection)? This is the sort of reasoning you seemed to use, so I'm curious when this holds in greater generality. Is it, for ex., when $X = c'(t)$ and $Y$ is any vector field (i.e., not just $c'$) along the curve $c(t)$?

Yes, think back to directional derivatives in multivariable calculus. Note, however, that what you wrote after “So that here” is very incorrect.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
